# Confused over NVIDIA graphic card is installed or not?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.10

Hi I have a doubt this command shows me these drivers :

```
$ apt-cache search nvidia | grep -P '^nvidia-[0-9]+\s'

nvidia-331 - Transitional package for nvidia-331 <br/nvidia-346 -
Transitional package for nvidia-346<br/nvidia-352 - Transitional
package for nvidia-361<br/nvidia-361 - Transitional package for
nvidia-367<br/nvidia-367 - NVIDIA binary driver - version
367.57<br/nvidia-304 - NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.134<br/nvidia-340 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.101<br/>
```

And but this command is showing me this result :

```
$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500
(rev 09)
```

making me confuse whether I have NVIDIA graphic card installed or not.
I don't really understand what all this means.

The output of :

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 5500 
Kernel driver in use: i915 
Kernel modules: i915

--
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1) 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GeForce 820M 
Kernel driver in use: nouveau 
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

but its not visible anywhere else. Have to install it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. That will answer your question.

Comment: `apt-cache search nvidia` only shows packages available in the repositories, but tells you nothing about installed/not installed. To see if any nvidia related packages are installed, run `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: @mikewhatever the output of **dpkg -l | grep nvidia**

is empty. I think the nvidia packages are not installed.Have to install them to use?

Comment: Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output of command **lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'** .  But it's not visible anywhere else.

Comment: @mikewhatever checked the link for installation but in additional driver section nothing is coming up related to NVIDIA. may be they are  bundled with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments: `apt-cache search` only shows available packages.

The second `lspci` output shows that you have an Nvidia GeForce 820M and it's currently using the nouveau driver (`Kernel driver in use: nouveau`). You can use `ubuntu-drivers` to show applicable packages or it's GUI frontend named `additional drivers` (can also be started from command line with `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`) and install the package you like.

Comment: ran the above command but didn't find anything in additional drivers section related to NVIDIA.may be they are bundled with Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you boot from a live CD/usb stick and try the same things again? It should at least show up on a fresh install.